# How do I set the correct content type in a WCF binding without using app.config?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a service reference to the CRM 2011 Organization.svc from a test console application. **Everything works perfectly using the binding generated in the app.config.** (Example of the service hosted by Microsoft [here](https://engineering.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc).)

This now needs to be moved into our "real" application and hosted in a DLL that will be deployed to the GAC. In following the app's conventions, the binding **needs to be generated by code**.

I've started off trying to use the binding we use for our other WCF services:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
binding.AllowCookies = true;
binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
```

Unfortunately at the point the WCF service is called (using the Execute method with an OrganizationRequest), this error occurs:

> **System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException:** Content Type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://server:5555/xrmservices/2011/organization.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

I'm not sure **what the specific problem is with the binding**, but my attempts at converting it to code have failed with the same error so far. Here's the working binding defined in app.config:

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding_IOrganizationService">
            <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="SspiNegotiated"
                requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Strict" includeTimestamp="true"
                keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature"
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
                requireSecurityContextCancellation="true" requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
                <localClientSettings cacheCookies="true" detectReplays="true"
                    replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00" maxCookieCachingTime="Infinite"
                    replayWindow="00:05:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="10:00:00"
                    sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="true"
                    timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" cookieRenewalThresholdPercentage="60" />
                <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" issuedCookieLifetime="10:00:00"
                    maxStatefulNegotiations="128" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00"
                    negotiationTimeout="00:01:00" replayWindow="00:05:00" inactivityTimeout="00:02:00"
                    sessionKeyRenewalInterval="15:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00"
                    reconnectTransportOnFailure="true" maxPendingSessions="128"
                    maxCachedCookies="1000" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" />
                <secureConversationBootstrap />
            </security>
            <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                messageVersion="Default" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </textMessageEncoding>
            <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Does anyone know how to set the correct binding in code and/or read the binding from XML?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a **custom channel factory** is a key part of solving this.

The article [Get your WCF client configuration from anywhere](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2010/07/29/Get-your-WCF-client-configuration-from-anywhere.aspx) is very helpful for reading a .config file from a location of your choice using a custom service client.

The alternative of setting all the values in a very similar way to the app.config format is described in [Calling WCF Service using Client Channel Factory](http://developergeeks.com/article/38/calling-wcf-service-using-client-channnel-factory) which describes how to create a custom binding. I found that not all of the security properties could be set this way (or at least I couldn't find them).

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same task to solve. This worked for me (for http).

```
var security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateSspiNegotiationBindingElement();
security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;
security.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
security.IncludeTimestamp = true;
security.KeyEntropyMode = SecurityKeyEntropyMode.CombinedEntropy;
security.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature;
security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;

security.LocalClientSettings.CacheCookies = true;
security.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = true;
security.LocalClientSettings.ReplayCacheSize = 900000;
security.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
security.LocalClientSettings.MaxCookieCachingTime = new TimeSpan(23, 0, 0, 0);
security.LocalClientSettings.ReplayWindow = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
security.LocalClientSettings.SessionKeyRenewalInterval = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);
security.LocalClientSettings.SessionKeyRolloverInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
security.LocalClientSettings.ReconnectTransportOnFailure = true;
security.LocalClientSettings.TimestampValidityDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
security.LocalClientSettings.CookieRenewalThresholdPercentage = 60;

security.LocalServiceSettings.DetectReplays = true;
security.LocalServiceSettings.IssuedCookieLifetime = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0);
security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxStatefulNegotiations = 128;
security.LocalServiceSettings.ReplayCacheSize = 900000;
security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
security.LocalServiceSettings.NegotiationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
security.LocalServiceSettings.ReplayWindow = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
security.LocalServiceSettings.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
security.LocalServiceSettings.SessionKeyRenewalInterval = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);
security.LocalServiceSettings.SessionKeyRolloverInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
security.LocalServiceSettings.ReconnectTransportOnFailure = true;
security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxPendingSessions = 128;
security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxCachedCookies = 1000;
security.LocalServiceSettings.TimestampValidityDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

var textEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
{
   MaxReadPoolSize = 64,
   MaxWritePoolSize = 16,
   MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Default,
   WriteEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
   ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
   {
       MaxDepth = 32,
       MaxArrayLength = 16384,
       MaxBytesPerRead = 4096,
       MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384,
       MaxStringContentLength = 8192
   }
};

var httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement
{
    ManualAddressing = false,
    MaxBufferSize = 65536,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536,
    AllowCookies = false,
    AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
    BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
    DecompressionEnabled = true,
    HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
    KeepAliveEnabled = true,
    MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288,
    ProxyAuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
    TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
    UnsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication = false,
    UseDefaultWebProxy = true,
};

var binding = new CustomBinding(new List<BindingElement> { security, textEncoding, httpTransport });
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(_serviceUri);

var service = new OrganizationServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
```